# RangeSelector display error when data is updated on zoomCallback

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am trying to update the charts data after zooming. This works so far using the zoomCallback. But when I use the range selector for zooming,
the range selector is not displayed correctly anymore. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tj7xajxo/27/) when using the range selector.

```
var data = [[1, 4, 5, 6], [2, 5, 6, 8], [3, 7, 4, 2], [4, 9, 6, 4]];

var gra = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("chart"),
    data,
    {
            labels: ["X", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3"],
            hideOverlayOnMouseOut : false,
            showRangeSelector: true,
            interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel,
            rangeSelectorHeight: 30,
            connectSeparatedPoints: true,
            legend: 'always',
            labelsDivWidth: 350,
    zoomCallback: function (minX, maxX, yRanges) {
        console.log("ZoomCallback!");
                updateDataOnZoom();
      },
}
);

function updateDataOnZoom() {
    var newData = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var newDataElement = [data[i][0]]; // use old Y-Value
    for (var j = 1; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        newDataElement.push(data[i][j] + 100); // calculate new X-Values
    }
newData.push(newDataElement);
}

gra.updateOptions({
    file: newData
});
}
```

Is there a way to solve this display error of the range selector?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Feel free to file an issue against dygraphs. A screenshot of exactly what's wrong would be helpful.

Comment: I have the same issue (after 6 years). It seems like after the `zoomCallback` event is fired, the rangeslider does not work anymore. You can still interactively change the zoom and the rangeslider's selected area changes appropriately, but the slider can no longer be dragged after the `zoomCallback` event.